# recreating nyquist regions using FFT python

Tags: nyquist

using python I have sampled a signal and made FFT to see the spectral picture of the time domain signal.
the plot bellow shows only 1st and 2nd nyquist zone.
I want to expend the spectral image and see the 3rd and 4th nyquist zones.

i have tried to double number of samples but it only expand the previos image two times.
where did i go wrong recreating addional  nyquist  zones?
Thanks.

```
Fs=200e3;#Hz
Ts=1/Fs;
dt=np.arange(0,1,Ts)
f1=10e3;
f2=20e3;
f3=30e3;
y=5*np.sin(2*pi*f1*dt)+5*np.sin(2*pi*f2*dt)+10*np.sin(2*pi*f3*dt)
L=np.size(y)
freq_vec=Fs*np.arange(0,1,Ts)
X=fft(y,L)
plt.plot(freq_vec,abs(X)/(0.5*L))
z=abs(X)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using the DTFT, not the DFT, for this task. The DTFT is defined for all frequencies, unlike the DFT (*).

Here's a plot of the magnitude of the DTFT of a sine wave of frequency 20 Hz, sampled at 100 Hz, from -200 to 200 Hz. You can clearly see the different Nyquist zones:

[image]

(*) Technically the DFT can be evaluated at any frequency (in other words, for any real $k$). However, the way it is usually implemented in the FFT does not easily allow for this flexibility.

My implementation of the DTFT in Julia. This function returns the DTFT of vector `wf` evaluated at `f0` (in Hz), with sampling frequency `fs`.

```
function dtft(wf::Vector{T}, f0, fs = 1.0) where T
    z = -2π*f0/fs
    x = zero(ComplexF64)
    n = 0
    @inbounds @simd for i ∈ eachindex(wf)
        x += wf[i]*cis(z*n)
        n += 1
    end
    x/length(wf)
end
```

Comment: Hello MBaz, is the a code example i could use for dtft transform? (Python will be great)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have it in Python, but someone must have implemented already. Anyway, it's really trivial to implement, it's a very simple formula. I code in Julia these days; I've added my code to the answer.